# A relation satisfied by the real Jordan form of a $2 \times 2$ matrix with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with complex eigenvalues, $\lambda_1 = \alpha + i \beta$ and $\lambda_2 = \alpha - i \beta$ ($\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$). We know that $u + iv$ is an eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$, where $u$ and $v$ are vectors with real coefficients.

> Show: If we have the matrix $P = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    u & v \\
>   \end{array} } \right]$, then $P^{-1} A P = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    \alpha & \beta \\
>    -\beta & \alpha \\
>   \end{array} } \right] =: J$, the real Jordan Canonical Form for $A$.

I don't know how to approach the problem. Since I don't know $P^{-1}$, I would consider $AP = PJ$ and then substitute A with $\tilde{P}\tilde{J} \tilde{P}^{-1}$, $\tilde{P} =  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   u + iv & u - iv \end{array} } \right] $ and $\tilde{J} = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \alpha + i \beta & 0 \\
   0 & \alpha - i \beta \\
  \end{array} } \right] $. Unfortunately, I couldn't came up with $\tilde{P}^{-1}$. Would appreciate some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $A$ is a matrix with real entries, we have\begin{align}A.(u-vi)&=\overline A.\overline{(u+vi)}\\&=\overline{A.(u+vi)}\\&=\overline{(\alpha+\beta i)(u+vi)}\\&=(\alpha-\beta i)(u-vi)\end{align}and therefore $u-vi$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\alpha-\beta i$. So\begin{align}A.u&=A.\left(\frac{u+vi}2+\frac{u-vi}2\right)\\&=\frac{(\alpha+\beta i)(u+vi)+(\alpha-\beta i)(u-vi)}2\\&=\alpha u-\beta v\end{align}and a similar computation shows that $A.v=\beta u+\alpha v$. Therefore, the matrix of $w\mapsto A.w$ with respect to the basis $(u,v)$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Answer (score 1):

Like you say, it suffices to show $A P = P J$, so we don't have to bother with computing inverses.

**Hint** By definition, we have $$A (u + i v) = \lambda_1 (u + i v) = (\alpha + i \beta) (u + i v) = (\alpha u - \beta v) + i (\alpha v + \beta u) .$$

On the other hand, by linearity we have
$$A (u + i v) = (A u) + i (Av) .$$